# Trying to create a std::map with a custom ordering

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, operator-keyword, stdmap

I'm answering a question from a Beginner C++ book. I'm doing a section on `std::map`. The question is to create a map with a sort predicate, and the map needs to be a custom struct (wordProperty) as the key and the definition (string) as the value.

I am getting the error;

Error   1   error C2664: 'bool fPredicate::operator ()(const std::string &,const std::string &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const wordProperty' to 'const std::string &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xutility 521 1   c++test1

Refers to Line 52 which is this part of the code:

```
bool operator < (const wordProperty& item) const
{
    return(this->strWord < item.strWord);
}
```

The program allows the user to input a word, input whether the word is from latin and input a definition, then prints the dictionary after each entry.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void DisplayContents(const T& Input)
{
for (auto iElement = Input.cbegin(); iElement != Input.cend(); ++iElement)
    cout << iElement->first << " -> " << iElement->second << endl;
cout << endl;
}

struct fPredicate
{
bool operator()(const string& str1, const string& str2) const
{
    string str1temp(str1), str2temp(str2);
    transform(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str1temp.begin(), tolower);
    transform(str2.begin(), str2.end(), str2temp.begin(), tolower);

    return(str1temp < str2temp);
}
};

struct wordProperty
{
string strWord;
bool bIsFromLatin;

wordProperty(const string& strWord, const bool & bLatin)
{
    this->strWord = strWord;
    bIsFromLatin = bLatin;
}

bool operator == (const wordProperty& item) const
{
    return(this->strWord == item.strWord);
}

bool operator < (const wordProperty& item) const
{
    return(this->strWord < item.strWord);
}

operator const char*() const
{
    string temp = this->strWord;
    if (this->bIsFromLatin)
    {
        temp += " is from Latin.";
    }
    else
        temp += " is not from Latin.";

    return temp.c_str();
}
};

int main()
{
map<wordProperty, string, fPredicate> mapWordDefinition;
while (true)
{
    cout << "Add a new word: ";
    string newWord;
    cin >> newWord;

    cout << "Is this word from Latin (Y/N)? ";
    string YN;
    bool newLatin;
    if ((YN == "Y") || (YN == "YES") || (YN == "y") || (YN == "yes") || (YN == "Yes"))
        newLatin = true;
    else
        newLatin = false;

    cout << "What is the definition of this word? ";
    string definition;
    cin >> definition;

    mapWordDefinition.insert(make_pair(wordProperty(newWord, newLatin), definition));

    cout << endl;

    DisplayContents(mapWordDefinition);

    cout << endl;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The predicate needs to work with the key type of the map.

Change

```
bool operator()(const string& str1, const string& str2) const;
```

to

```
bool operator()(const wordProperty& wp1, const wordProperty& wp2) const;
```

In the implementation of the function, you can extract the `strWord` member of the objects `wp1` and `wp2` and follow your logic.

Comment: hey, thank you for this. So I changed the code to this;

 struct fPredicate
 {
  bool operator()(const wordProperty& wp1, const wordProperty& wp2) const
  {
   string str1temp = wp1.strWord;
   string str2temp = wp2.strWord;

   return(str1temp < str2temp);
  }
 };

But it is now saying "wp1" and "wp2" are undeclared identifiers.

Comment: @JonathanCain, I am confused. You accepted my answer right after your comment. Should I assume that you were able to resolve your problem?

Comment: No sorry, I just thought you've fixed the previous error so I ticked it, I didn't manage to resolve the identifier problem...

Comment: @JonathanCain, the problem might be that `wordProperty` is defined after `fPredicate`. You can move the definition of `wordProperty` before `fPredicate` to see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Ah wait, I have it, I just had the predicate declard before wordProperty. Thank you.